# SQL : why can't a database contain databases

Tags: sql

I have to admit I am a newbie in SQL and rdbms and so on but I have the following question (which I think is pretty clear already from the topic).

My question is more a "philosophical" one. What would be the downside of allowing a database in SQL to contain not only tables but also "sub"-databases?

E.g. outer database `media` which contains databases `video` and `audio`. I know it is not allowed my question is if someone could maybe enlighten me on what was the idea or upshot of not allowing the above.

For me such a more complex schema could give better organization over the SQL server and database.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What would be the benefit? You can simply construct any number of databases you want...

Comment: You can always create a set of tables which have some prefix to them: prefix1_users, prefix2_users...

Comment: I also see no real benefit. I have used different schema's in the past to split up some tables belonging together in a single database, although, even that was an exceptional case. I'd just create multiple databases.

Comment: Why? Simply let the database have several schemas.

Comment: This would be like defining a class inside another class.. or writing a function inside another function

Comment: As others have pointed out, the whole approach makes no sense... But there is one exception: Generic structures. If you need to work with data, where you do not know the structure in advance... In this case I tend to use XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relational database isn't just a bit of structured data.  It's an implementation of a [relational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) and [first order predicate logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic).  Tables, rows, keys, each have specific roles.  It isn't arbitrary.  "Sub-databases" have no role in that system.

A database is much more than just a namespace for you to organize your database objects.  A database is a unit with particular characteristics.  It has a single tran log; it is a boundary for referential integrity; operations within the database are coordinated according to a chosen concurrency mode.  I am not sure how any of those would work if a database could contain other databases.

But there are database systems other than relational out there.  Sounds like you might be interested in an [Object Oriented Database Management System](http://www.25hoursaday.com/whyarentyouusinganoodbms.html), which lists among its advantages:

> Composite Objects and Relationships: Objects in an OODBMS can store an arbitrary number of atomic types as well as other objects. It is thus possible to have a large class which holds many medium sized classes which themselves hold many smaller classes, ad infinitum. In a relational database this has to be done either by having one huge table with lots of null fields or via a number of smaller, normalized tables which are linked via foreign keys. Having lots of smaller tables is still a problem since a join has to be performed every time one wants to query data based on the "Has-a" relationship between the entities. Also an object is a better model of the real world entity than the relational tuples with regards to complex objects. The fact that an OODBMS is better suited to handling complex,interrelated data than an RDBMS means that an OODBMS can outperform an RDBMS by ten to a thousand times depending on the complexity of the data being handled.
>
> Class Hierarchy: Data in the real world is usually has hierarchical characteristics. The ever popular Employee example used in most RDBMS texts is easier to describe in an OODBMS than in an RDBMS. An Employee can be a Manager or not, this is usually done in an RDBMS by having a type identifier field or creating another table which uses foreign keys to indicate the relationship between Managers and Employees. In an OODBMS, the Employee class is simply a parent class of the Manager class.

Comment: And yet there *are* relational models that incorporate recursion. I.e. the Third Manifesto's`Wrap` operator could apply.

Comment: Not sure what recursion has to do with this question.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: you think a question about databases *containing* databases *isn't* about recursion?

Comment: thnx. i accepted your answer because it technically gives an answer to a "technical" why in my question, since you mentioned "first order logic", which means one universe of discourse so one type of variables. Also you mentioned the oodbms which was sth that might be more close to my interest. But i have to say that you did not answer the intuitional why, which refers to why this architecture and not a more complex one. but ok your answer is actually much better than i expected to get. thnx

Comment: @Damien: I have an open mind about it.  The OP's example does not require recursion.

Comment: I'm not sure what definitions you're working from. But "type X contains an instance of type X" **is** [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type)

Comment: In this case, type X contains type Y and Z.  Y and Z are subtypes of X, e.g. Video is a special case of Media.  There is no recursive type here. Anyway, the `Wrap` operation has no bearing on any of this, as far as I can tell, which is why I asked you to elaborate.

Comment: `X` is "database". Y is "database". Per the question asked.

Comment: I guess if they had the exact same schema.  I don't see any practical use for that.  Perhaps if you could provide an example of how this relationship would be used?  Thanks for your comments.